# running my code when other function called Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, userscripts

I am writing a user script (for greasemonkey) to a website.
This website uses Ajax to change the HTML without reloading, and i want to add some buttons every time the page changes.
The function that does it called "ajaxHandlerCall".

Is there a way to load my function every time this function called? ("event" of calling the function)

Thanks.

Comment: Is `ajaxHandlerCall` a function on the global scope?

Comment: ajaxHandlerCall is a function of the original page.

Comment: I got that much, but is is accessible in your script?

Comment: yes, i can use it from my script.

Comment: Then you may be able to do something like:  `var old = ajaxHandlerCall; ajaxHandlerCall = function(event){ /* do Stuff */; old(event) }`

Comment: Great, I added it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to do something like:

```
var oldHandler = ajaxHandlerCall;
ajaxHandlerCall = function(event){
    /* do Stuff */
    oldHandler (event);
}
```

Basically, you're wrapping the old handler in a function of your own.